# WebSphere Portal 8 Installation - Trial Installation

Tags: db2, websphere, websphere-portal

Trying to install IBM WebSphere Portal 8 Express Version from this [link](https://www-01.ibm.com/marketing/iwm/iwm/web/pickUrxNew.do?source=ESD-PORTALEXPRESS).

Once the installation starts, below error is captured in the Installation Manager logs.

```
 [exec] C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\ConfigEngine>db2 -v "CREATE DB wpsdb USING CODESET UTF-8 TERRITORY US PAGESIZE 8192" 
 [exec] CREATE DB wpsdb USING CODESET UTF-8 TERRITORY US PAGESIZE 8192
 [exec] SQL1092N  "XXXXXXX" does not have the authority to perform the requested 
 [exec] command or operation.


 [exec] C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\ConfigEngine>db2 -v "UPDATE DB CFG FOR wpsdb USING applheapsz 4096" 
 [exec] UPDATE DB CFG FOR wpsdb USING applheapsz 4096
 [exec] SQL1013N  The database alias name or database name "WPSDB" could not be found. 
 [exec] SQLSTATE=42705
```

Additional Details:

- OS - Windows 10
- User used - Is an admin, also added to the user groups **DB2ADMNS** and
  **DB2USERS**.
- Purpose - Setup an existing project on Portal 8 and then upgrade to
  Portal 9.

  Any suggestion or link to download IBM WebSphere Portal Enable/Extend version will help.

Comment: Run the `db2 -v "create db wpsdb ...` in a DB2CMD.EXE window that is running as administrator. Click Start > Run >db2cwadmin . Also ensure that the account "XXXXXXX" (which you have masked) is a local-administrator and a member of local-group DB2ADMNS.  If your workstation is part of a DOMAIN then additional changes may be needed (DB2_GRP_LOOKUP registry variable value change).

Comment: @mao - Thanks for the reply, I am already running Installation Manager as an administrator. Please elaborate on "DB2_GRP_LOOKUP registry variable value change", since my id is part of my organisation's domain. Also, want to state that the DB2 Installation is part of Portal Installation package.

Comment: @mao - the problem is that DB2 is used as Portal Internal Database and it comes along with WebSphere Portal setup. So the setup tries to install DB2 and it fails; then rolls back everything including the partial install of DB2. So, I do not have the privilege to run DB2 specific commands or refer to the table SYSPROC.AUTH_LIST_AUTHORITIES_FOR_AUTHID mentioned in the article you shared. Can you share what registry update you want me to make for DB2, Windows registry path where I see a DB2 reference is - Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\IBM\DB2\INSTALLEDCOPIES

Comment: Edit your question to fix the link to the WAS portal 9 express, because currently the link is malformed.  Additionally *verify* that the software is supported on the Windows-10 (some IBM server software will only work on *server* editions of Windows products, or might not support Windows-10). So check that whatever you are using is supposed to work on Windows-10 for whatever edition of Windows-10 you are using.

Comment: @mao - corrected the link. This version was released around 2012, so support for Windows 10 is not explicitly mentioned. But in the installation logs I do not see any OS related errors yet, hoping it has to do with some DB2 configuration changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the Portal Installation has an integrated DB2 setup which tries to add users to Domain instead of the Local Machine. In order to fix this, create an user in the local system and add the user to these user groups -  Administrator, DB2ADMNS and DB2USERS.

Steps to add user:

1. Type lusrmgr.msc from command prompt.
2. Add User from "Local Users and Groups > Users" tab.
3. Add User to Administrator, DB2ADMNS and
   DB2USERS groups from "Local Users and Groups > Groups" tab.

Thanks @mao for the clue.